# Characteristic functions and metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the space of probability measure on $\mathbb{R}.$ Define $d(\varphi,\phi)=\sup_x|\varphi(x)-\phi(x)|/(1+|x|),$ where $\varphi$ and $\phi$ are the characteristic functions of two measures $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from $\mathcal{P}$. Show that this a metric and equivalent to the Lévy metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric).

it's easy to see that $d$ is a metric since, $\mu=\sigma$ implies $d(\varphi,\phi)=0$ and if $d(\varphi,\phi)=0$ then $|\varphi(x)-\phi(x)| \leq (1+|x|)d(\varphi,\phi)=0,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$

We also have $d(\varphi,\phi)=d(\phi,\varphi)$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},| \varphi(x)-\phi(x)| \leq |\varphi(x)-h(x)|+|h(x)-\phi(x)|,$ for three characteristic functions $\varphi,\phi,h$ and so we have $d(\varphi,\phi) \leq d(\varphi,h)+d(h,\phi).$

So my question is how to prove that $d$ is equivalent to the Lévy metric, denoted $d'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d(\phi_n,\phi) \to 0$. Then $\phi_n(x) \to \phi(x)$ for every $x$ and hence the corresponding measures converge weakly. This implies convergence in the Levy metric.

Conversely if $\phi_n \to \phi$ in the Levy metric then $\phi_n \to \phi$ uniformly on compact sets.  Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $M$ such that $\frac  1 {1+|x|} <\epsilon /2$ for $|x| >M$. Choose $m$ such that $|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)| <\epsilon $ for $|x|\leq M$  and $n \geq m$. Then $d(\phi_n,\phi) \leq \epsilon$ for $n \geq m$.

Comment: We can't prove that $\exists c_1>0,c_2>0$ such that $c_1 d' \leq d \leq c_2d'$?

Comment: I mean without using the convergence

Comment: I don't think so. And that is not necessary either. To prove that two metrics are equivalent we only have to check that they have the same convergent sequences with the same limits.

Comment: Proving the inequalities, even if they are true, is a lot lot more difficult.

Comment: Yeh, you're right, we don't have $c_1d' \leq d \leq c_2d',$ in Chung's book, Course in Probability Theory, he provides a note on this, with countrexample (page 173-174)

Comment: In the above solution, did you use the fact that $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|/(|x|+1)| \leq sup_{|x| \leq M}|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|+\frac{1}{M+1}$ and then taking $limsup_n  sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|/(|x|+1)| \leq \frac{1}{M+1}$ and we conclude by taking the limit $M$ at $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, but you need $2/(M+1)$.

Comment: Yeh, I made a mistake, Thank you for your help!